# Не могу скачать базу данных. Выдает ошибку

Tags: phpmyadmin

Не могу скачать базу данных. Выдает ошибку.

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>   Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать то, о чём просит текст ошибки?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте удалить все сессии и почистить кэш, а затем перезапустить phpMyAdmin

Comment: Проблема только с одной базой, которую не могу скачать, все остальные скачиваются.